# I get three related errors when trying to push a commit to github concerningproc/10/exe. What should I do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, github

When trying to commit to github I get these errors after I type the command

```
$ git add .
```

1. $ error: readlink("proc/10/exe"): No such file or directory
2. $ error: unable to index file proc/10/exe
3. $ fatal: adding files failed

Google doesn't have much to say about these errors. Do you guys have any idea what I should do?

Comment: Seems you forgot [init repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository)